# Splitting of a string with | delimited

Tags: java, string, scala, apache-spark

`"abc|xyz|".split("\\|").foreach(println)` ===> only displaying `abc` and `xyx`

`println("abc|xyz|".split("\\|").length)`  ===> length should be 3 but is showing as 2.

When I split a string with pipe delimited, and the value of the last column is empty. The split function is ignoring the last value.

Comment: What should be displayed for each test case?

Comment: The `split` function is Java's String.split, so I'm marking this as duplicate of a similar Java question with a great detailed answer.

Comment: What do you expect for this last value?  There is nothing there except for a zero width boundary marker, hence, nothing gets added to the array of split strings.

Answer (score 3):

You should be using `limit` with `split` function as -1 which will give you as expected

```
"abc|xyz|".split("\\|", -1).foreach(println)
```

Which results in output as `abc`, `xyx` and `''`

```
println("abc|xyz|".split("\\|", -1).length)
```

This results in length as 3

Comment: Perhaps you could explain why this works.  From a pure regex split point of view, rightfully nothing _should_ be in the third position, because there is only a boundary marker in between the last pipe and end of string.